# Does the uncertainty of the ratio of two distributions suppose to decrease with correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, covariance-matrix

I need to calculate the variance of the ratio B/(A+B) between two correlated distributions A and B which  are known with their variances.

```
set.seed(123)
nn        <- 10000
mean.A   <- 37   
mean.B   <- 18
sigma.A  <- 5 
sigma.B   <- 3
A   <- rnorm(nn, mean=mean.A,  sd=sigma.A)
B   <- rnorm(nn, mean=mean.B, sd=sigma.B)
```

I know that A and B have correlated PDFs, and I want to analyse how the ratio B/(A+B) behaves by increasing the correaltion coefficient between 0 and 1:

```
sd.emi.perc <- vector(); k<-1
for (r in seq(0,1,0.1)){ # loop over increasing correlation 

  # create covariance matrix with increasing value of correlation:   
  cov.matrix <- matrix(c(sigma.A^2, rep(r*sigma.A*sigma.B,2), sigma.B^2), nrow=2  )
  
  # generate two distributions with prescribed level of correaltion:
  
  sample <- mvrnorm(nn, c(mean.A, mean.B), cov.matrix, empirical=T)  # mvrnorm from library MASS

  # use the two distributions to calculate the ratio:
  ratio <- sample[,2]/(sample[,1]+sample[,2])  # simulate the share ratio (B/(A+B))
  
  # get the standard deviation 
  unc.MC <- sqrt(var(ratio))
  # get the percentage 
  sd.emi.perc[k] <- unc.MC/(mean(ratio))
  
  k <- k+1
}
```

When I do the plotting `plot(sd.emi.perc)`  I get that the standard deviation is larger for the case of no correlation and decreases as the correlation increases.
[image: the x axis is the index of the correlation coefficient: Index =0 means correaltion =0; Index=11 means correlation =1.]

any idea why? any suggestion to get the right estimate?
thanks

Comment: For intuition, consider what happens when $A$ and $B$ are perfectly correlated.

Comment: @whuber thanks for replying but i m afraid I need more than a hint! Can you please be more explicit? What happens when A and B are fully correlated?

Comment: The ratio is a constant.

Comment: thanks again but still don't see it. is it correct to get a higher standard deviaiton when A and B are uncorrelated? why? I would really appreciate some help